# waiting for a function to finish to call other in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm new in nodejs and javascript for that matter and i want my function to run one after another has finished, i have read about async, but i don't get the callback concept that well. here the functions:

```
orchestrator.sentiment(parameters, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error en sentiment:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('sentimiento encontrado:' + response.docSentiment.type);
    if (response.docSentiment.type == 'negative') {
      params.input == 'negative';
    }
  }
});
orchestrator.conversation(params, function(err, results) {
  if (err)
    return next(err);
  else
    res.json({
      conversation: results
    });
});
```

orchestartor.sentiment must finish before i can run orchestrator.conversation because as you can see params.input is going to be use in orchestrator.conversation, thanks!

Comment: Put `orchestrator.conversation` inside the `orchestrator.sentiment` callback. Easy way to understand. Temporarily comment out a callback functions and what you see is who JavaScript will run the *first* time. Asynchronous functions like `sentiment` return immediately and essentially ignore the callback till later.

Comment: This is a good use case for async. Have you looked at [`async.series`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series)?

Comment: @Sukima thanks you put me in the right direction!

Comment: @1252748 i have not, but i am definitly doing it, thanks!